# Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "... No module named 'sklearn.impute._base'; 'sklearn.impute' is not a package. (Error code: 0)"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to create a version on google cloud ai platform but it can't find the impute module

```
No module named 'sklearn.impute._base; 'sklearn.impute' is not a package
```

[image]
The Framework version is sklearn 0.20.4 though and last I checked the doc 0.20.4 has the sklearn.impute api.

page 1785
https://scikit-learn.org/0.20//_downloads/scikit-learn-docs.pdf

Is the whole sklearn package included in the ai platform? Is there a workaround (don't really want to write a custom imputer) or am I using the ai platform wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) 0.20.4 is included in latest runtime version [1.15](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list) and older versions.

From scikit-learn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html that function is included in 0.20.4:

I tried locally with Python 3.5/3.7 and invoking that method worked fine:

```
...
scikit-learn==0.20.4
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
tensorboard==1.15.0
tensorflow==1.15.2
tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
termcolor==1.1.0
Werkzeug==0.16.1
wrapt==1.11.2

...
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
>>> imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
>>> imp_mean.fit([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])
SimpleImputer(copy=True, fill_value=None, missing_values=nan, strategy='mean',
       verbose=0)
```

The default AI Platform Training runtime version used by the AI Platform Training and Prediction API is version 1.0. If you do not specify a runtime version, AI Platform Training uses version 1.0.

Make sure you set the correct runtime version when launching the job:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_job \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --job-dir gs://my/training/job/directory \
    --package-path /path/to/my/project/trainer \
    --region us-central1
    --runtime-version 1.15
```

Question: Can you share how are you launching the job and setting the runtime version?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues in the past. The sklearn package is included in the AI platform, however, if you trained your model using a different version to the one the AI plaform is using you need to go back and retrain the model using the same scikit-learn version as the one the AI platform's runtime is using.

Hope this helps!